# How to solve Signature issue after system upgraded to iOS15

Tags: ios, xcode, in-house-distribution, ios15

When my device upgraded to iOS15 beta1, the installed Enterprise App cannot launch success.

ErrorMsg : Signature Version Unsupported, reason: Signature version no longer supported

current code sign version is 20400

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: iPhone update to iOS 15 beta, and our App can't be install or run.

Comment: please look my answer

Answer (score 3):

### I have the same problem,I solve this problem through the following steps:

- go to Targets-General-Frameworks,Libraries,and Embeded Content
- Find the frameworks that are set to `embed & sign`
- `Show in Finder` of this Framework
- in `Terminal` run `file xxx.framework`(`cd /XXX/XXX/thirdSDK.framework`)
- if you see `current ar archive`，Indicates that this is a `static` library。(if you see `shared Library`，Indicates that this is a dynamic library.)
- if this framework is `current ar archive`,just need to set `embed & sign` to `Don's signing`。Then everything will be ok.

Comment: The right answer, thank you.

Comment: @Geek__Lee Didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade macOS version and repackage ipa.